# send message from server to specific clients

Tags: java

```
for (Iterator<Integer> iter = clients.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
{
    int key = iter.next();
    String addresses="ZeeshanNisar";

    java.net.Socket client = clients.get(key);
    System.out.print("ok3");
    InetAddress zee = client.getInetAddress();
    String s = zee.getHostName();
   // String s=client.getInetAddress().toString();
    System.out.print(s);
    if (zee.getHostName()=="ZeeshanNisar")
    {
        System.out.print("ok4");
        dos =new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeUTF("Some message");

    }
```

This piece of code is to send the message for a specific client connected to the Server let suppose the client name is zeeshannisar  but in this my code isn't go to the if statement as there is no mistake as far as i think kindly help me.Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thankyou so much bro u have solved my problem @azurefrog

Comment: Practically everybody learning Java runs into the whole `==` vs `equals()` thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to replace == with equals

```
if(zee.getHostName()=="ZeeshanNisar")
```